# Python CSV printing issue

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a problem with printing using python's csv package.

I want the headers to come out as "header 1, header 2, header 3, header 4"

But what I get is:

> h,e,a,d,e,r, ,1
>
> h,e,a,d,e,r, ,2
>
> h,e,a,d,e,r, ,3
>
> h,e,a,d,e,r, ,4

My codes look like this:

```
def write_to_excel(file_name, obj_lst):
with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)

    # Write the headers first
    writer.writerow(['header 1', 'header 2', 'header 3', 'header 4'])
    for obj in obj_lst:
        writer.writerows(obj)
```

On a separate piece of code, the above code works just fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I ran your code and works fine for me. Not able to re-produce the error.

Comment: I imagine you could expect such an output if you mistakenly add `s` to make `writer.writerows(['header 1', 'header 2', 'header 3', 'header 4'])`

Comment: @MayankPorwal Exactly why i have to ask for something so simple on stackoverflow because on my other codes it worked fine. Just this particular code is giving me this error. I am completely bam-boozled. I think my code is possessed.